# GNOME Terminal > load-config > does not work properly after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal

That command below worked fine on Ubuntu 14.04. After upgrade to 16.04 it does not work anymore. It opens a terminal window with 4 tabs.

open-terminals.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --load-config=terminal-config.cfg &>/dev/null &
```

terminal-config.cfg

```
#Written by GNOME Terminal 3.6.2

[GNOME Terminal Configuration]
Version=1
CompatVersion=1
Windows=Window0;

[Window0]
MenubarVisible=true
Role=gnome-terminal-window-6355-887453268-1466588933
ActiveTerminal=Terminal0xed4f70
Geometry=135x24+437+495
Terminals=Terminal0xe04970;Terminal0xc1f520;Terminal0xe4f060

[Terminal0xe04970]
ProfileID=Default
Title=am.example.com
WorkingDirectory=/home/.../servers/apache-tomcat-am/bin
Zoom=1
Width=135
Height=24

[Terminal0xc1f520]
ProfileID=Default
Title=web.example.com
WorkingDirectory=/home/.../servers/apache-tomcat-web/bin
Zoom=1
Width=135
Height=24

[Terminal0xe4f060]
ProfileID=Default
Title=middleware.example.com
WorkingDirectory=/home/.../servers/payara-middleware/bin
Zoom=1
Width=135
Height=24

[Terminal0xed4f70]
ProfileID=Default
Title=api.example.com
WorkingDirectory=/home/.../servers/glassfish-api/bin
Zoom=1
Width=135
Height=24
```

At first I got a `"Error creating terminal: "Default" is not a valid UUID" error`. I fixed it so that I put a real uuid to ProfileIDs.

Next error what I got was `"Error creating terminal: No profile with UUID "e4661004-d5fd-4d17-9a9d-8e419b6b8330" exists"`. I fixed it so that I changed the value of Terminals in [Window0] to the ProfileIDs.

Next problem: Title and WorkingDirectory properties are not applied and i just realized that the "rename tab" menu is disappeared from the menu.

GNOME Terminal

3.18.3

A terminal emulator for the GNOME desktop

Using VTE version 0.42.5 +GNUTLS

Could you please help me to fix this issue?

**update**

`gnome-terminal --save-config=~/temp/xyz.cfg` says that `Option "--save-config" is no longer supported in this version of gnome-terminal.`

What is that? What is is the alternative way to do the same with the new version of gnome-terminal? I have not found any useful about this topic on the internet :(

Answer (score 1):

Same issue.

On my computer the command line parameter `--tab-with-profile` accepted value "Default", while `--load_config` did not (check tag `<entry name="visible_name">` in the file ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/%gconf.xml or use GUI profile settings).

So I have transformed important values from the config file to command line parameters. You can use following code for your setup:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry="135x24+437+495" \
            --tab-with-profile="Default" --working-directory="/home/.../servers/apache-tomcat-am/bin" \
            --tab-with-profile="Default" --working-directory="/home/.../servers/apache-tomcat-web/bin" \
            --tab-with-profile="Default" --working-directory="/home/.../servers/payara-middleware/bin" \
            --tab-with-profile="Default" --working-directory="/home/.../servers/glassfish-api/bin"
```

Unfortunately I haven't found how to set tab titles this way.

But there are sweets in the end. You can use `--command` for each tab and run e.g. `mc`. This was impossible with config file.

Comment: Finally i use Terminator. Install: sudo apt-get install terminator LINK: http://www.tenshu.net/p/terminator.html

Answer (score 0):

I've got same issue. Partly fix is to comment all lines where

```
ProfileID=Default
```

...it provides load all your tabs from configuration saved before. But tab name issue should be fixed (I've checked `--help` & `--help-all` - have not found correct property for tab title)

Other way to have hot fix is to replace `ProfileID` `name` value with `id` value. `Id` value can be checked in `Edit`->`Profile parameters`->`General`->`profile ID`.